# Help Adding another view to GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, admob

I am trying to add another view to my GlSurfaceView however I keep kicking up errors.

```
 glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        glView.setRenderer(this);
        setContentView(glView);

        glView.setId(932203934);
        int newID = glView.getId();

            // Create the adView
        AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14e3ef0948eb58");
        // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
        // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        //LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(newID);
        GLSurfaceView layout = (GLSurfaceView)findViewById(newID);
        // Add the adView to it
        this.addContentView(layout, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        //layout.addView(adView);
        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

I have added "setID" as the glView always gave -1, but now with this I get "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

Clearly I am not doing this right so how do I had this additional view to the glsurfaceview?

Thanks

Comment: GLSurfaceView is not a ViewParent. Your root view should be a RelativeLayout. Give that an id so you can findById() it and then call addView() on it to add the adView.

Comment: Sorry I dont use any xml right now but I currently dont have any RelativeLayouts, why do I need to create one now? I tied to add a new LinearLayout and created that as an xml however that returns null when I do the following...  LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone else having this problem....

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14e3ef0948eb58");
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.addView(adView);
        this.addContentView(ll, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
        request.setTesting(true);
        adView.loadAd(request);
```